# How to solve this error with my services ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I get this error when I start my app:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Data.Access.Layer.Interfaces.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Data.Access.Layer.Repositories.UnitOfWork': Unable to resolve service for type 'Data.Access.Layer.EFContext' while attempting to activate 'Data.Access.Layer.Repositories.UnitOfWork'.)'

My code:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

public interface IUnitOfWork: IDisposable 
{
        IGenericRepository<ApplicationUser> Users { get; }
        IGenericRepository<Painting> Paintings { get; }
        IGenericRepository<OrderItem> OrdersItems { get; }
        IGenericRepository<Order> Orders { get; }
        IGenericRepository<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; }
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
        private readonly EFContext _eFContext;

        private GenericRepository<ApplicationUser> _users;
        private GenericRepository<Painting> _paintings;
        private GenericRepository<Order> _orders;
        private GenericRepository<OrderItem> _ordersItems;
        private GenericRepository<ShoppingCartItem> _shoppingCartItems;

        public UnitOfWork(EFContext eFContext)
        {
            _eFContext = eFContext;
        }

        public IGenericRepository<ApplicationUser> Users => _users ??= new GenericRepository<ApplicationUser>(_eFContext);

        public IGenericRepository<Painting> Paintings => _paintings ??= new GenericRepository<Painting>(_eFContext);

        public IGenericRepository<Order> Orders => _orders??= new GenericRepository<Order>(_eFContext);

        public IGenericRepository<OrderItem> OrdersItems => _ordersItems ??= new GenericRepository<OrderItem>(_eFContext);

        public IGenericRepository<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems => _shoppingCartItems ??= new GenericRepository<ShoppingCartItem>(_eFContext);

        private bool disposed = false;

        public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                   _eFContext.Dispose();
                }
                this.disposed = true;
            }
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
}
using AutoMapper;
using Business.Layer.Interfaces;
using Business.Layer.Services;
using Data.Access.Layer.Entities;
using Data.Access.Layer.Interfaces;
using Data.Access.Layer.Repositories;
using Presentation.Layer.Mapping;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile).Assembly, typeof(BLAutoMapperProfile).Assembly);
var app = builder.Build();





if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: It seems like you didn't register the `EFContext` as service before `IUnitOfWork`, have you done that?

Comment: Can you share your Program.cs? Maybe something wrong about registration.

Comment: @QingGuo I added, look pls

Comment: @NPS your EFContext hasn't been register.

Comment: Read [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#register-groups-of-services-with-extension-methods) to know more about register your EFcontext.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to call your attention to this part of your error message, because it tells you exactly what the problem is:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Data.Access.Layer.EFContext' while attempting to activate 'Data.Access.Layer.Repositories.UnitOfWork'.)

This tells you that the dependency injection container tried to create an instance of `UnitOfWork`, but was unable to do so, because that class has a dependency on `EFContext`, which was not registered with the container.

Your UnitOfWork class is registered here:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

It basically means "hey, container, when I ask you for an `IUnitOfWork`, you should provide me with an instance of `UnitOfWork`".

But, as mentioned, `UnitOfWork` has a dependency:

```
public UnitOfWork(EFContext eFContext)
{
    _eFContext = eFContext;
}
```

To get an instance of `UnitOfWork`, you need an instance of `EFContext`. When the container realizes this, it's going to check if `EFContext` has been registered with the container. But you haven't told the container about `EFContext`, so it has no way to provide you with a `UnitOfWork`.

To solve the error, you need to inform the container that you have something called `EFContext`. For an Entity Framework `DbContext`, this is usually done with the `AddDbContext` extension method:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<EFContext>();
```

You might also need to pass some options to this method, depending on how you're configuring your context.

Here's a few documentation links that goes more in depth:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/